# CSS background cover/fit or similar with radial gradient?

Tags: css

I want a radiant gradient background that is a circular, not ovoid. I want it to scale to the fit the container, which may not be square.

Cover/contain don't treat radial-gradient like a square image, which I suppose makes sense.

Setting background width to 100% operates X and Y independently still.

Setting a fixed px size doesn't allow it to scale to the container.

Are there any pure-CSS ways to make this happen? Maybe a special property value to make the radial gradient act "square" for cover/contain sizing?

```css
.gradier{
  height:200px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgba(0,255,255, 0.2) 55.5%, rgba(0,255,255,1) 56%, rgba(0,255,255,1) 57%, rgba(0,255,255, 0) 57.5% );
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradier"></div>
```

Comment: If the element itself is not a perfect square, how should the circle adjust? Do you want it to base itself off of the lower value (not covering the entire element) or the higher one (with some parts cut off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `circle closest-side`

```css
.gradier {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2) 96%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 1) 97% 98%, #0000);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradier"></div>
```

Or `circle farthest-side`

```css
.gradier {
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background: radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.2) 96%, rgba(0, 255, 255, 1) 97% 98%, #0000);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradier"></div>
```